# Этимология: блошиный рынок и барахолка. В чём сходства и отличия?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, выбор-слов, история

***Барахолка*** — куплю, продам, обменяю...

***Рынки*** в Праге: Гавельский, Пражский и **Блошиный**.

"*Поиски раритетов среди пугающих на первый взгляд куч старого хлама во многом похожи на захватывающий квест: кто знает, какое сокровище вам удастся откопать?"*
[**Блошиные рынки и барахолки Петербурга**](https://kudago.com/spb/list/bloshinye-rynki-i-baraholki-peterburga/)

Хотелось бы узнать мнение Форума:
Почему именно **"блошиный рынок"** ( не клоповий, не тараканий...)?
**Есть ли разница между блошиным рынком и барахолкой?**

Answer (score 4):

Блоши́ный ры́нок (нем. Flohmarkt, фр. Marché aux puces, англ. Flea market) (разг. барахо́лка) — место, где люди продают и покупают старые, подержанные вещи, как правило изготовленные много лет назад. Почему «блошиный»?

Одно из объяснений  можно найти в книге Жана Беделя, одного из самых авторитетных специалистов в области истории Парижа и, в частности, Блошиного рынка. Жан Бедель, автор книги «Блошиному рынку сто лет», связывает происхождение значения этого выражения с французской пословицей «Тот, кто ложится спать с собаками, наутро просыпается с их блохами». Смысл пословицы заключается в том, что плохие, неправильные поступки обязательно имеют нежелательные последствия. Это также означает, что  точно так же, как собачьими блохами, можно заразиться чем-то другим, коллекционированием,  поисками пиратских сокровищ или же копей царя Соломона, например, а также и перепродажей вещей иди поиском среди старых вещей настоящих ценностей, которые несведущие люди выбрасывают на помойки. А заразиться поиском раритетов на таких рынках помогают романтические истории, легенды. Рассказывают, как некий старьёвщик по фамилии Давыдофф купил на Блошином рынке картины Тулуз-Лотрека, выброшенные его родственниками на помойку, и разбогател. Рассказывают, как так же случайно на Блошином рынке были куплены дагерротипы известного фотографа Надара, от которых несведущий их владелец решил избавиться. Счастливчик, их обнаруживший, тоже разбогател. Всеми этими многочисленными историями питается легендарный романтический образ Блошиного рынка.

Есть и другие версии, все правдоподобные.

1.Человек, который роется в куче старых вещей,  напоминает своим поведением того, кто ищет блох. Часто вещи были  старые и неухоженные, попадались и с насекомыми.

2.Чисто лингвистическое. Название «блошиный рынок» является калькой с французского языка, его русские эквиваленты – толкучка, барахолка. Но к нам пришло через немецкий (Flohmarkt – первая часть созвучна с «блох»). Нужно сказать, что рынки называются блошиными, хотя речь здесь идёт о вшах. Слово «Floh» употребляется в немецком языке для обозначения и вшей, и блох.

Во французском же сыграло роль и благозвучие. По-французски словосочетание «marché aux puces» воспринимается как благозвучное. Оно звучит приятнее для уха, чем, например, «marché aux cafards» - «тараканий рынок»

3.И еще одно обстоятельство возникновения названия - случайность. Однажды  незнакомец, увидев кучи старья и людей на французских улочках, крикнул: «Здесь как на блошином рынке».

Если верить этой версии, то блошиные рынки образовались в период с 1880 по 1900 г. в Saint-Ouen, перед воротами Парижа. Что же касается глубинной его сути, то в неё никто особенно вникать не стал.  В своей печатной (не фольклорной) форме выражение «блошиный рынок» впервые появилось не в газетах, как то можно было бы предположить, а в надписях на почтовых открытках. Мода на открытки стала распространяться как раз в конце 19 века, как раз в те годы, когда впервые в пригороде Сент-Уан появилась первая более или менее цивилизованная парижская барахолка, получившая столь необычное название – Блошиный рынок.

Первыми продавцами в Cант Уане(Saint Ouen) - первом блошином рынке в Париже были так называемые chiffoniers. На русский этот род деятельности переводится как старьевщики. Chiffoniers стояли во французском табеле о рангах на 1 место выше чем мусорщики(balayeurs). Иногда их романтично называли лунными ловцами (pecheurs de la lune). 
Хозяева ресторанов, лавок, богатых доходных домов в центре Парижа, перед  сном выносили мусор из заведений, а старьёвщики начинали поиски сокровищ. Утром особо ценные находки перекочевывали на лавки рынков для бедняков. После войны 1870 года  они облюбовали Сант Уан и основали там рынок. В 1885 года власти Сант Уана в целях безопасности обязали торговцев официально регистрировать свои места продаж на рынке и вместе с этим он начал превращаться из хаотичного собрания chiffoniers в цивилизованный рынок поддержанных вещей. http://antikdesign.livejournal.com/9274.html

После Второй мировой войны идею блошиных рынков подхватили и другие европейские страны.

Сейчас блошиными рынками называют организованные места продаж, а толкучки и барахолки - неорганизованные, часто на площадях перед рынками просто на тряпках располагались торговцы подержанными вещами. По-моему, сейчас их разогнали.Может быть, в том числе и из гигиенических соображений.